# Please explain this code from watchr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning to use watchr, a ruby gem that watches files and runs something if they change

```
watch( 'test/test_.*\.rb' )  {|md| system("ruby #{md[0]}") }
watch( 'lib/(.*)\.rb' )      {|md| system("ruby test/test_#{md[1]}.rb") }
```

Specifically, I don't understand what `md[0]` and `md[1]` are. I know that `'test/tests_.*\.rb'` is a regular expression and it's retrieving a list of files. I also know that `|md|` represents filenames that match the regular expression. But I'm not sure what `md[0]` and `md[1]` would point to

Comment: `md` is most probably an `Array` or a class that's implemented the `[]` method (so, `[0]` is referring to the first element of that Array). Do a `md.class.name`, `md[0].class.name` and go from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby's regular expression operator (=~) returns an object that responds to :[]. The values 0 and 1 refer to the matched string and the first group (the part in the parentheses).

So for example if the strings being tested were:

```
"test/test_sample.rb"
"lib/sample.rb"
```

Then the first expression (/test/test_.*.rb/) would match "test/test_sample.rb", and the second expression (/lib/(.*).rb/) would match "sample". You can see this in the console:

```
> /test\/test_.*\.rb/ =~ "test/test_sample.rb"
# => 0
> $~[0]
# => "test/test_sample.rb"
> /lib\/(.*)\.rb/ =~ "lib/sample.rb"
# => 0
> $~[0]
# => "lib/sample.rb"
> $~[1]
# => "sample"
```

`md` stands for `MatchData`, which is the class of the object Ruby uses to return the result of the regex match.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `md` is a [`MatchData`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html) instance, where `[0]` it the entire matched text and `[1]` is the first captured sub-expression), in this case the filename inside the `lib` directory, without the extension.

Answer (score 0):

zetetic's answer is correct; `md` is an instance of Rudy's `MatchData` class, which is the result of applying the regular expression on the modified file (see `String#match`).

The relevant line from the Watchr source code is at: https://github.com/mynyml/watchr/blob/17fa9bf80998483f9cf69a934bbcb726a0c389fa/lib/watchr/script.rb#L204